# How to save quotes as a string in mysql using java?

Tags: java

Basically I have `String str="That's an apple and that's not an apple, hah. Not funny."`. FYI: The string could be random and could contains any unicode character  . I need to add `\` before all `'` & `"` so I could it save in my mysql db as a row value. And if you might, would you tell me before what other characters do I need to add `\`.

I would really appreciate if somebody tell me how to add `\` before all `'` & `"`.

---

Based on recommendation you gave me I happen to come to do this:

```
public String UpdateDBQuery(String query, int hm) throws IOException{
    try {
        DBConnect mysql_DB = new DBConnect();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        for(int i=0;i<hm;i++){
            ps.setString(i, query);
        }

        int ursa = ps.executeUpdate(query);
        if (ursa == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
        } else {
            return "succeed";
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the queries which then I am calling:

```
mysql.UpdateDBQuery("UPDATE tb1 SET ste='"+str1+"' WHERE pd='"+pd+"'", 1);
```

And

```
mysql.UpdateDBQuery("INSERT INTO list(str, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5) VALUES ('"+str+"', '"+str1+"', '"+str2+"', '"+str3+"', '"+str4+"','stackdefaultimage.png')", 6);
```

But I am getting an exception saying:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).

Comment: "so I could it save in my mysql db as a column value" - it sounds like you're trying to embed the value in your SQL statement. **Don't do that.** Use parameterized SQL instead, and just set the value of your parameter as the original string. This is simpler, more reliable, and is by far the best way to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: More on why not to do that, and what to do instead: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I meant row value. BTW I don't directly send mysql output result to the client I am getting the required data from mysql respose  and send it to client and if an exception happened I am replying with something went wrong. I think That might pervent from mysql injection right?

Comment: No, absolutely not. This isn't about what's sent to the client - it's about what's sent to the *database*. Follow the link from T.J. Crowder - it's **really, really important** that you understand this.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add `\` before all `'` & `"` so I could it save in my mysql db as a column value.

No, you don't need to do that. Instead, you need to use parameterized statements ([`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and such). Just escaping `'` and `"` will leave your code wide open to SQL Injection as well as non-malicious errors.

Instead:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Table (Column) VALUES (?)");
ps.setString(1, yourString);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

...or similar. Note the use of `?` as a placeholder, and note that when setting values for placeholders, they start at 1 (rather than 0 as you might expect).

More here: http://bobby-tables.com/

---

**If** you needed to replace all `'` with `\'` and all `"` with `\"` for some *other* reason (not related to prepping a string for SQL), you could do that with [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
str = str.replaceAll("([\"'])", "\\\\$1");
```

but **don't do that to pre-process values for SQL**. The `()` in the replacement regex create a capture group, and the `$1` uses the value of that group in the replacement. To insert the backslash in the replacement, we have to double-escape it because we need to escape it for the string literal *and* in the replacement string (otherwise, it escapes the `$` and prevents the group substitution).

Again: **Do not** do that to prepare values for SQL statements. Use `PreparedStatement` and similar.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I just did you said But I am getting an exception you can read the update in my question.

Comment: @mrjorden: Read more carefully. From the answer: *"and note that when setting values for placeholders, they start at 1 (rather than 0 as you might expect)."*

Comment: @mrjorden: And you need to pass in the strings individually, not as a single `query` string. What your code is trying to do is use the same string for all of the parameters.

Comment: So I need to have my query inside my Updatequery, I can't actually get the query from outside from another function. am I right?

Comment: @mrjorden: Please refer to the examples on the given link, and various Java DB tutorials.